# Import CSV file into SQL (PostgreSQL or BigQuery)

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

My problem is that I have a dataset from Kaggle (I'm currently doing this Google Analytics Capstone Project; FitBit tracker dataset). These are CSV files and contain the timestamp in the 12-hour format [m/dd/yyyy hh:dd:mm AM / PM] which cannot be imported into PostgreSQL or BigQuery directly. My question is that what should I do in order to be able to import these data and work with them? I don't intend to use Excel/GSheet to transform the timestamp because I want to learn the necessary method (and why it works) and I could not use the Sheets for this anyway.

So, can you help me with this, please?

Thank you in advance & have a nice day.

I tried to change datestyle in PostgreSQL, but it didn't work (but I can imagine that I did not try everything).

Comment: What did you try to change the date style? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT

Comment: I tried 'SQL' as an output format specification, because I saw this suggestion somewhere. Honestly, I am a beginner with an SQL bootcamp, but this kind of issue was not mentioned before and I looked up some websites and haven't found anything yet. I have just found some comments at this dataset on Kaggle and some recommended settings in BigQuery. But I haven't succeeded yet.

Comment: This is my date style: ISO, MDY
And this one works fine: SELECT '5/25/2014 11:23:05 PM'::timestamp; -- 2014-05-25 23:23:05

Comment: Can I do this while importing the CSV file?

Comment: First check your date style: SHOW datestyle; And if needed, change it. After that you can import your data again

Comment: It is the default: 'ISO, MDY'

Comment: Works fine over here, so what's the exact error message you get when you import the data? (and do you use INSERT or COPY to import the data?)

Comment: I created the table and its columns manually with the use of "Create" --> "Table" / "Column" commands, but not with codes in the Query tool. The import was tried with both the COPY query and the Import/Export command.

Comment: And I'll show you the error message in a minute.

Comment: ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM"
HINT: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
CONTEXT: COPY MinuteStepsWide, line 1442, column ActivityMinute: "4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM"
Failed (exit code: 1).

Comment: And the datestyle is 'ISO, DMY', I've just checked it

Comment: DMY is not the same as MDY and explains the issue: Month 13 doesn't exists.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it. Now, I'm facing other error messages. :D

Comment: Id,ActivityMinute,Steps
1503960366,4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM,0

Comment: These are the columns and the kind of values I try to import. Now, I tried to give 'Serial', 'Timestamp' and 'bigint' data types, but I does not work.

Comment: Well, I tried "SET datestyle TO 'ISO, MDY', but next, when I'm asking it with "SHOW datestyle" it's 'ISO, DMY' again. How can I save this setting?

Comment: Maybe your using a different database connection?

Comment: Oh, I've found the root cause of the problem. First, I've made some mistakes, but after that I've found that I should change the access of the files I am working with, because the access was denied. Thanks for helping me! Have a nice day!